# Filtering Multiple Columns with List

Tags: python, filter

I am just starting to learn Python.

Say I have an excel file with multiple columns and rows, example as such:

```
     A               A.1    B              C
0    abc Insurance   123    INSUR          1.01
1    def INSUR       456    insurance      2.05
2    ghi gift        789    gift           10.05
3    jkl pte ltd     101    gas            1.89
```

I want to filter rows for columns A and B containing the words "insurance" and "gift".

I could do `df[df['A'].astype(str).str.contains('insu',case=False)]` for column A containing 'insu'.

However, is there a better way to filter columns A and B containing a list of words? Due to the nature of the excel file, the columns A and B are Dtype object, although I think can I could use astype(str).

I am running Jupyter Notebook 6.3.0 and Python 3.8.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex with all the target words (be sure to escape the special characters), then use boolean indexing to slice:

```
import re

lst = ['insu', 'gas']

regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, lst))
mask = df[['A', 'B']].apply(lambda s: s.str.contains(regex, case=False)).any(1)

df2 = df[mask]
```

*NB. using `any` here to select rows with **any** match (use `all` if you want to match on **all** the columns)*

output:

```
               A  A.1          B     C
0  abc Insurance  123      INSUR  1.01
1      def INSUR  456  insurance  2.05
3    jkl pte ltd  101        gas  1.89
```